# Algebraic simplification involving grouping of terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking at a solution of a problem that I am solving, here is that solution:

[image: Solution of problem]

I dont understand the step from the second line to the third line. How does $$p(2p - 1)^{n-1} - \frac12(2p-1)^{n-1}$$ become $$\frac12(2p-1)(2p-1)^{n-1}$$? I just don't understand what is exactly applied here, to turn this into a multiplication and turning the exponent from $n-1$ to $1$.

Comment: $p(2p - 1)^{n-1} - \frac12(2p-1)^{n-1}=\left(p-\frac12\right)(2p-1)^{n-1}=\frac12(2p-1)(2p-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: @Aiden That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Deepak Alright then.

Comment: @Aiden Thanks, upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Steinar This question has not much to do with linear algebra and nothing to do with either abstract algebra or calculus. Please choose your tags better in future. I'll edit them this time. I've also edited your title to correspond better to the subject of your question.

Comment: thanks. Excuse me, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

$$p(2p - 1)^{n-1} - \frac12(2p-1)^{n-1}\\=\left(p-\frac12\right)(2p-1)^{n-1}\\=\frac12(2p-1)(2p-1)^{n-1}$$